# Why I can print the values of this indexed array inside this HTML table?

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I am trying to print out the values of an array inside a table in HTML but for some reason that I cant understand this code is not working. it is only printing the table rows, header and counting numbers but not the values inside the table:

```
    function buildTable($data = [], $header = []): string
{

    $table = ""; // the container for the html table

    /* open table */
    $table .= '<table>';
    $table .= '<tr><th class="rowcount">#</th>'; // output header for row-count (first column)

    // output the table headers
    foreach ($header as $key => $value) {
        $table .=  '<th>' . $value . '</th>';
    }
    $table .=  '</tr>'; // end of header row

    $rowCount = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $table .=  '<tr>'; // open a new row (for a new record in the array)
        $rowCount++;
        $table .=  '<td class="rowcount">' . $rowCount . '</td>'; // print row-count in first column

        foreach ($value as $key => $value1) {
            $table .=  '<td style="border: 1px solid black;">' . $value1 . '</td>'; // print data in column
        }

        $table .=  '</tr>'; // close table row
    }
    $table .=  '</table>';

    return $table; // the container with html table
}
```

**And here is the array:**

```
Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 321 [2] => test_device [3] => 123 [4] => 321 [5] => 33 [6] => [7] => test_device [8] => 123 [9] => 321 [10] => [11] => 77 [12] => test_device [13] => 123 [14] => 321 [15] => 88 [16] => [17] => test_device [18] => 123 [19] => 321 )
```

> EDIT

I have an array which looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 321 [2] => test_device [3] => 123 [4] => 321 [5] => 33 [6] => [7] => test_device [8] => 123 [9] => 321 [10] => [11] => 77 [12] => test_device [13] => 123 [14] => 321 [15] => 88 [16] => [17] => test_device [18] => 123 [19] => 321 )
```

but instead, I want it to look like this format (same array just few more values added):

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 166 [report_id] => 272 [userID] => 2 [address] => Eriksvej [city] => Slangerup [zipcode] => 4000 [country] => Denmark [username] => manufact1 [user_Name] => Manufacturer 1 [rma_id] => 272 [serial_imei] => 123 [serial_no] => 321 [name] => test_device [manufacturer] => 2 [device_no] => 123 [barcode] => 321 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 166 [report_id] => 272 [userID] => 2 [address] => Eriksvej 42C, 1. 56B [city] => Slangerup [zipcode] => 4000 [country] => Denmark [username] => manufact1 [user_Name] => Manufacturer 1 [rma_id] => 272 [serial_imei] => 33 [serial_no] => [name] => test_device [manufacturer] => 2 [device_no] => 123 [barcode] => 321 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 166 [report_id] => 272 [userID] => 2 [address] => Eriksvej  [city] => Slangerup [zipcode] => 4000 [country] => Denmark [username] => manufact1 [user_Name] => Manufacturer 1 [rma_id] => 272 [serial_imei] => [serial_no] => 77 [name] => test_device [manufacturer] => 2 [device_no] => 123 [barcode] => 321 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 166 [report_id] => 272 [userID] => 2 [address] => Eriksvej  [city] => Slangerup [zipcode] => 4000 [country] => Denmark [username] => manufact1 [user_Name] => Manufacturer 1 [rma_id] => 272 [serial_imei] => 88 [serial_no] => [name] => test_device [manufacturer] => 2 [device_no] => 123 [barcode] => 321 ) )
```

This is the way I am pushing to the first one:

```
array_push($myArray, $new_case);
```

And this is in the second:

```
array_push($myArray, $new_case['serial_imei'], $new_case['serial_no'], $new_case['name'], $new_case['device_no'], $new_case['barcode']);
```

Comment: 1)have you checked $table that it contains what you expect? 2)what do you do with it when returned from function?

Comment: @DCR I print the $table but as I said it prints only the layout, not the values!

Comment: @DCR this code works properly if there are arrays inside the array, but not with the kind of array I have posted in the question!

Comment: how are you accessing the array?

Comment: @DCR I dont understand your question. If you mean how am I printing it, I just print_r($table). dont focus in that part, everything is fine there, just let me know if you know how can I actually push those values as array inside that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have flat, single level, array. And you have foreach in foreach after that. Very simple your `$value` is not an array and in your second foreach `$value1` is always NULL. remove that second foreach just print / concatenate `$value`.

If I understood what you want.

EDIT:

Try like this:

```
$finalArray = [];
$finalArray[] = $myArray;
$someNewArray = [ $new_case['serial_imei'], $new_case['serial_no'], $new_case['name'], $new_case['device_no'], $new_case['barcode']];
$finalArray[] = $someNewArray;
```

and pass that $finalArray as $data in your function that returns html table.

Comment: I need to print them in rows, the way you said it will print everything under one single column.

Comment: Then you need to format your $data before they reach this function. And I have no idea what you want with that data, or how your table should look like on the end. Should all be in one line?

Comment: I need to print everything inside a table

Comment: Is there any other requirement. Single line is also inside a table. :)

Comment: yea, but there are multiple rows in this case and multiple columns. Please check my Edited question.

Comment: If I understood well: you shouldnt array_push to previous array. You should create new empty array with $arr = []; and then array push all that arrays in that new one. Does it help? Did I understood you? And it is simpler and faster to use $arr[]  = $newArr; then array push.

Comment: I think you misunderstood it, those are two separate cases, I just posted the way I am doing it in two different cases. The first case is the one that I wanna use but unfortunately doesnt work, the second case is the way it works but I dont wanna use it.

Comment: First way that doesnt work is array_push($myArray, $new_case);? Right? What is $new_case ? array or simple value?

Comment: this one works perfectly fine: array_push($myArray, $new_case); the other one doesnt work. The only thing I need is to format this simple array into an array of arrays.

Comment: this one needs to be formated to array of arrays: array_push($myArray, $new_case['serial_imei'], $new_case['serial_no'], $new_case['name'], $new_case['device_no'], $new_case['barcode']);

Comment: Did that helped?

Comment: I am inside a loop so I am doing it like this: $someNewArray = [$new_case['serial_imei'], $new_case['serial_no'], $new_case['name'], $new_case['device_no'], $new_case['barcode']];
                            
                        array_push($myArray, $someNewArray);

Comment: btw peace from Kosova :)